# Best filesystem for flexible virtual machine setup?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, virtualization

I start up new ideas every once in a while building out an actual dedicated server to try something that if it worked, would need a great server, but of course not all my ideas are slam dunks and so sometimes I end up with a very overbuilt machine. While I may not want to completely abandon the idea and wipe the server, it isn't being used to it's potential.

With that in mind, I have a couple Dell R720xd 96GB RAM and with 12x2TB drives in them that I setup with Xenserver. The goal is to be able to partition the server into a bunch of virtual servers, and see which ideas take off, those that do get more resources till they get a dedicated server, the others get scaled back.

For operating systems I typically use Ubuntu 16.04 or CentOS 7.

Should I use EXT4 or LVM or something else? Is it better to install the OS and give it 10GB at first and then grow if needed, or give them 500GB and shrink if needed?

I know the old Partition Magic on Windows used to let me resize partitions with the computer running, but most of the tutorials I have seen involve shutting down the server and booting from the LiveCD - which then may get tricky if the server is in a data center. Xenserver so far has been much better to work with than ESXi as far as networking and booting - so maybe that isn't a big deal, I am just trying to be smart up front and choose the right filesystem.

I tried Btrfs and when one of the drives failed in the 15 disk array, the whole thing became unusable even though it was supposed to have redundancy, so am just trying to be careful. When I was building dedicated servers, I chose EXT4 because it seemed to have better support than LVM in data recovery software, but in the virtual environment that may be a non issue.

Comment: On Ubuntu my personal fav is a 20GB HD (thin provisioned), with LVM which is mostly enough, and if it needs more space I add another disk of the appropriate size and add it to the LVM - this for VMs to play with. For production I think another approach depending of the use would be needed (mount points: /, /var/log, /home and whatever else is needed for the purpose - again on LVMs). Of course /boot on EXT4. I use the 'think of VM as of physical servers" - as you can not reduce a 500GB physical disk to be a 20GB (ok it is possible), I do not do it with VMs.

Comment: You might look into [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com/en/) which is built above Xen and offers the possibility to grow a disk offline and online - [see here](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Resize_disks) - but I like the add another disk to LVM more, add a hard disk to the VM, and then add it to the pool and resize.